# How to calculate the height of a red black tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I'm almost done implementing a red black tree, but I'm stuck with *how to calculate the height* (**not black height**). Can anyone give me a hint or the concept on how to implement the height? I know the formula, but it's not much of a help.

I thought of traversing each node and adding a counter, but this gets complicated as the red black tree gets bigger.

Basically how do I know when it has travelled down to its longest path?

I'm not really concerned with the time complexity of the solution, but I would like to avoid n<sup>2</sup>.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to know the 'true' height without explicitly keeping track or DFSing it. The black height is really all that's important. I'd assume the worst case 'true' height is ((2*black height)-1) since the root and the leaves HAVE to be black AND every red parent HAS to have two black children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple recursive approach for computing the height of a tree that works in time O(n), where n is the number of nodes. The idea is to compute the heights of each node's children, then to take the maximum of those values, plus one. Here's some pseudocode:

```
function treeHeight(node n) {
    if (n is null) return -1;
    return max(treeHeight(n.left), treeHeight(n.right)) + 1;
}
```

This visits every node exactly once and does O(1) work per node, so the total time complexity is O(n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: How would you take the maximum of those values? Well I mean you can compare it but how do you know when to compare and to what to compare and such

Comment: @user2472706- I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to compute the maximum of two values?

Comment: Sorry I will rephrase it. What would max be from your pseudocode in terms of implementation?

Comment: @user2472706- Something like "if x < y, return y, else return x." As long as you don't recompute x and y, this should be linear. (That said, any implementation that recomputes x and y is a very silly implementation!)

Comment: Alright. This is sort of similar to how I was going to compute the height. After I get off work I will attempt to implement using this idea and hopefully come out with something. Thanks.